# Complexity of a constrain-modified $0$-$1$-knapsack problem

Tags: computational-complexity, information-theory, integer-programming, np-complete

If the constrain of a $0$-$1$-knapsack problem was replaced with a 2-SAT formula, e.g.

$\begin{align}\textrm{maximize} && \sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_i p_i \\
\textrm{s. t.} && (x_1 \lor \lnot x_4) \land (x_3 \lor \lnot x_2) \land \dots \textbf{= 1} \\
\\
x_i \in \{0,1\} \; ,  \; p_i \in \mathbb{Z} \quad \forall \; 1 \leq i \leq n\\
\end{align}$

**will this problem still be NP-hard?**

Basically I am optimizing among the solutions of a propositional 2-SAT-formula. (Solving the formula itself is in $\mathcal{P}$, obviously)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you describe is [0-1 integer programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) slightly disguised.  This is a known NP-hard optimization problem.

Maximizing $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_i p_i$ translates directly to the maximizing $c^Tx$ with the $p_i$'s appearing in the $c$ vector.  The 2-SAT clauses can be reduced to a series of linear inequalities.  E.g. $(x_3 \lor \lnot x_2)$ translates to $x_3 + (1 - x_2) \geq 1$.  Each positive $x_i$ variable appears as itself and each negated $x_i$ is written as $1 - x_i$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how would you prove my problems complexity to be at least as difficlult as 0-1 integer programming? Wouldn't this require to show that every instance of 0-1-IP problem could be converted to an instance of mine?